# What makes the address bar in IE turn green?

Tags: security, internet-explorer, ssl, certificate, https

What aspect of a site's SSL certificate causes IE's address bar to turn green?

I'm working on a site which already uses SSL successfully, but am interested to know if there are different *levels* of certificate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it is a different *level* of certificate, as you say.

It's green when it is an **Extended Validation Certificate**.  See [Extended Validation Certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate) at Wikipedia: "[...] a special type of X.509 certificate which requires more extensive investigation of the requesting entity[2] by the Certificate Authority before being issued. [...]"

The cheapest of certificates are usually domain-validation only, meaning the only thing that the certificate authority is guaranteeing is that the requestor of the certificate has control of the domain name.  That's a very low threshold.  The extended validation certificates require more than that.  For instance, they verify the legal status of the business that is requesting the certificate, etc.

Comment: It's also a good way for the certificate authorities to make extra cash. Those green address bar certificates are not cheap.

Comment: There's a list of the different browsers and how/what they show EV vs Standard at: https://www.expeditedssl.com/pages/visual-security-browser-ssl-icons-and-design.html